# How can define variable inside smarty template file?

Tags: php, smarty

How can i define variable not in `PHP` but in `.TPL`? (smarty template file)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
{assign var=foo value=Test}
```

or some more complicated example:

```
{assign var=foo value={cycle values="first,second"}}
```

Comment: Does that second example actually work (in versions 2.*)?

Answer (score 2):

is [assign](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign) what you are looking for?